# Python 2 parameters, as independent

Tags: python, arrays, string, parameters, substring

I am stuck and I do not know what to do. I have software to which a script is added. This software passes 2 parameters

`sys.argv[1]` and `sys.argv [2]`

But the software passes the 2 parameters as a string.

EDIT:

How can I separate these 2 parameters to interpret them as independent parameters?

My software use the variable $MOST_REPEATED$ --> like this: 192.168.1.1 1.2.3.4

```
host = sys.argv[1]
ip_src = sys.argv[2]
```

Comment: show us an example and/or the code you're using :)

Comment: What code you have written and error are you getting?

Comment: If you're asking "How do I split a string?", then I suggest `str.split`.

Comment: @Kevin I dont have access to the parameter `$MOST_REPEATED$` so, i cant use `str.split`

Comment: I don't understand. Variable names in Python can't have dollar signs in them. Is your software not written in Python? If not, why is this post tagged as Python?

Comment: @Kevin

My software is written in python, but it is from another development. I have neither code can I change it.

The software stores in $MOST_REPEATED$ some data that comes from a log.

Answer (score 0):

You can use raw_input("Arg1: ") , raw_input("Arg2: ") instead of sys package.